# Convert rmarkdown presentation to a set of images

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to make an rmarkdown presentation (ioslides or revealjs) but then take the final product and convert it to a set of images. The reason being that I want to share it through a medium that cannot render html but can show a slideshow of images.

I don't care if this is through ioslides or revealjs and I am fine with using some other tool to do the conversion, I'll even take crazy hacks. One thought I had was to write some python (with Selenium) that takes a screen shot at the end of each slide but would like to avoid writing this code if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your "set of images" could be in PDF format then you could follow the suggestion from [R Studio on their page on ioslides presentations](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#printing_and_pdf_output).

> **Printing and PDF Output**
>   You can print an ioslides presentation from within browsers that have good support for print CSS (i.e. as of this writing Google Chrome has the best support). Printing maintains most of the visual styles of the HTML version of the presentation.
>
> To create a PDF version of a presentation you can use Print to PDF from Google Chrome.

This works with ioslides. I'm not sure if it works with the new version of `reveljs` but the old one has a bug so that it only saves the first page when printing to pdf ([see here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/206))

Comment: Yes, I saw that feature but I need png/jpeg instead of pdf. Do you know if it's possible to convert that pdf into a set of images?